# How can I make my procedure for finding the Nth most frequent element in an array more efficient and compact?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

Here's an example of a solution I came up with

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 }; 
        var countlist = arr.Aggregate(new Dictionary<int,int>(), (D,i) => { 
                                        D[i] = D.ContainsKey(i) ? (D[i] + 1) : 1;
                                        return D; 
                                      })
                            .AsQueryable()
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                            .Select(x => x.Key)
                            .ToList();
        // print the element which appears with the second 
        // highest frequency in arr
        Console.WriteLine(countlist[2]); // should print 3
    }
}
```

At the very least, I would like to figure out how to

- Cut down the query clauses by at least one. While I don't see any redundancy, this is the type of LINQ query where I fret about all the overhead of all the intermediate structures created.
- Figure out how to not return an entire list at the end. I just want the 2nd element in the enumerated sequence; I shouldn't need to return the entire list for the purpose of getting a single element out of it.

Comment: Is it okay if you use .Skip() and .FirstOrDefault()  right before .ToList()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 };

var lookup = arr.ToLookup(t => t);
var result = lookup.OrderByDescending(t => t.Count());

Console.WriteLine(result.ElementAt(1).Key);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this.

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 }; 


int rank =2; 
var item = arr.GroupBy(x=>x)          // Group them
   .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count())   // Sort based on number of occurrences
   .Skip(rank-1)                      // Traverse to the position
   .FirstOrDefault();                 // Take the element


if(item!= null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    // output - 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I started to answer, saw the above answers and thought I'd compare them instead.

Here is the [Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DxfRNk).

I put a stopwatch on each and took the number of ticks for each one.  The results were:

```
Orignal: 50600
Berkser: 15970
Tommy: 3413
Hari: 1601
user3185569: 1571
```

It appears @user3185569 has a slightly faster algorithm than Hari and is about 30-40 times quicker than the OP's origanal version.  Note is @user3185569 answer above it appears his is faster when scaled.

update:  The numbers I posted above were run on my pc.  Using .net fiddle to execute produces different results:

```
Orignal: 46842
Berkser: 44620
Tommy: 11922
Hari: 13095
user3185569: 16491
```

Putting the Berkser algortihm slightly faster.  I'm not entirely clear why this is the case, as I'm targeting the same .net version.

Comment: I can't get nearly the same numbers using the same link, i'm getting `12663` for Hari's

Comment: That's interesting.  The numbers I posted were from my pc, and then a posted the code up to fiddle.  I've rerun mutliple times and get approximately the same numbers each time, I'm not sure why it's so different on fiddle.

Comment: Can you check my answer. I think it is much much faster than all these.

Comment: done.  see edit above.  Your's is faster on my pc, but not fiddle.  I would ignore the fiddle results as who knows what's being done behind the scenes there.

Comment: This is a small array, i added an example of an array of 100,000 random numbers.

Comment: Interesting. GroupBy uses Lookup inside its implement. But GroupBy is faster in your test.

Comment: Okay, you mixed up my solution with berkser's solution.

Comment: sorry about that.  fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, this is a very interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the the following mash of Linq and a dictionary as what you're looking for is essentialy an ordered dictionary

```
        void Run()
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
        int[] unique = arr.Distinct().ToArray();
        Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = unique.ToDictionary(k => k, v => 0);

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if(dictionary.ContainsKey(arr[i]))
            {
                dictionary[arr[i]]++;
            }
        }

        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> solution = dictionary.ToList();
        solution.Sort((x,y)=>-1* x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value));
        System.Console.WriteLine(solution[2].Key);
    }
```